# Copy a row in a different spreadsheet based on the text on google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want a code or a Formula that can copy a row to another spreadsheet based on the text on the column B, but i just want to copy the Column A,B,C and D...so for example, if column B name is Stator, i want to copy the row to the spreadsheet Stator, if the name is Alternator, i want to copy the row to Alternator Spreadsheet.

I already tried this one:

```
function yourfunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("Stator");
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Prototype Number");
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(1,2,sh1.getLastRow(),sh1.getLastColumn()-1);//starting at column2
  var data=rg1.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(data[i][6]=="Estator") {
      sh1.getRange(i+1,2,1,sh1.getLastColumn()-1).copyTo(sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,sh1.getLastColumn()-1));
    }
  }
}
```

But didn't work.

I also tried a macro record, but didn't work because I couldn't find a way to paste the row to a new row every time.

Comment: what is your main sheet which has the data? the `Stator` ?

Comment: No, my main sheet is a sheet with the data of stators and alternators

Comment: yes but what is the name of that sheet? You don't seem to use it anywhere..

Comment: and why do you start from column B (starting at column2) if you want to copy A,B,C and D ?

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

- Assuming you have data in columns `A,B,C,D` in a main sheet `Main`. Your goal is to copy the rows (`A-D`) to the corresponding sheet its name matches the value in column `B`.
- You need to iterate over all sheets, and filter only the data (rows) for which column `B` matches that sheet name. You can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the sheets and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter based on the sheet name - column `B`.

---

### Solution:

Feel free to adjust the name of the sheets or also the ranges but do respect the logic of the script, otherwise it won't work properly.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const main_sheet = 'Main';
  const msh = ss.getSheetByName(main_sheet);
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const data = msh.getRange('A2:D'+msh.getLastRow()).getValues();
   
  sheets.forEach(sh=>{ 
    if(sh.getName()!=main_sheet){
      let temp_ar = data.filter(r=>r[1]==sh.getName());
    if (temp_ar.length>0){
      sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,temp_ar.length,temp_ar[0].length).setValues(temp_ar);                 
    }}});
}
```

**Structure of my example file:**

[image]